# Excel Formula to total amount quarterly in date row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to calculate the difference between total current quarter and total previous quarter in Excel.  The data is at the row title and the quarter month is not standard.  For example January is consider as quarter 4 and February is quarter 1.  Also date can change from one report to the next.

This is the sample data:
[image]

I want to add a formula in column H that total all amount in Q4 (Nov-Jan) and in column I the total amount in Q1 (Aug-Oct) for **every row**.  Next month report column G will be February and I need a formula  that dynamic enough to know the current quarter amount to be placed in column H.

I was thinking about using sumproduct and choose but Excel does not like it:

```
=Sumproduct(--((CHOOSE(MONTH(B29:G29),4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)=4),B30:C30))
```

If this formula can work, I can just copy paste it to the remaining row in column H and I.

Comment: I think you were trying to use `{=SUMPRODUCT(--(CHOOSE(MONTH($B$29:$G$29),4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)=4),$B30:$G30)}` for that formula, i.e. `G30` instead of `C30`, and removing the extra bracket before `CHOOSE` and after `B30:C30`, and making it an array formula (and making certain references absolute rather than relative)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on above example use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(1+MOD(INT((MONTH($B$29:$G$29)-2)/3),4)=RIGHT(H$29,1)*1),$B30:$G30)
```

Comment: I like the sumproduct better than formula array as I have many worksheets with similar data.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With this array formula at `H30` would do what you want and you can copy paste in `I30` and in the rows down. It will work also if you add columns for Q2 and Q3.

```
H30 -->
 =SUM(IF(CHOOSE(MONTH($B$29:$G$29),4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)=INT(RIGHT(H$29,1)),$B30:$G30))
  Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

Notice it takes the quartile's number from the row above, it fixes the columns and parametrizes with the row.